# Как вставить видео на сайт с только одной кнопкой вкл/выкл звук?

Tags: html, css

Искал в интернете, но так и не понял, как можно реализовать. Нужно вставить на страницу видео, с тегами и атрибутами разобрался, но то что мне нужно так и не нашел, а именно добавить видео и что бы у него была только одна кнопка включения/выключения звука, как на некоторых сайтах вставляется реклама.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К сожалению, мой код не очень красиво выглядит на сайте, но как "скелет" думаю подойдет.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>autoplay</title>
 </head> 
 <body>
  <video id="video" width="400" height="320" autoplay="autoplay" muted loop>
   <source src="ваше видео.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
  </video>
  <button id="volume">Звук</button>
  <script>
    var video = document.getElementById("video");
    var volume = document.getElementById("volume");
    volume.addEventListener('click', function() {
    video.muted = (video.muted == false) ? true : false;
    });
  </script>
 </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Сразу предупреждаю, звук по умолчанию выключен